# Getting ATLAS 3.10.0 compiled on Windows 7 64

Tags: compilation, mingw, windows-7-x64, atlas

I'm having some difficulty compiling ATLAS on Windows 7 64-bit and any help would be appreciated! I'm trying to link it to lapack-3.4.1.

The command I'm using in Cygwin is:

```
../ATLAS/configure -D c -DWALL --with-netlib-lapack-tarfile=../lapack-3.4.1.tgz -b 64 -Si archdef 0 -Ss ADdir ../ATLAS/WINAD
```

The output I get is:

```
make: `xconfig' is up to date.
./xconfig -d s /f/Coursework/Code/python/compile/built/../ATLAS/ -d b /f/Coursework/Code/python/compile/built  -D c -DWALL -Si lapackref 1 -b 64 -Si archdef 0 -Ss ADdir ../ATLAS/WINAD
gcc.exe: error: /f/Coursework/Code/python/compile/built/../ATLAS//CONFIG/src/probe_asm.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [probe_asm.o] Error 1
gcc.exe: error: /f/Coursework/Code/python/compile/built/../ATLAS//CONFIG/src/probe_vec.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [probe_vec.o] Error 1
gcc.exe: error: /f/Coursework/Code/python/compile/built/../ATLAS//CONFIG/src/probe_arch.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [probe_arch.o] Error 1
gcc.exe: error: /f/Coursework/Code/python/compile/built/../ATLAS//CONFIG/src/probe_arch.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [probe_arch.o] Error 1
gcc.exe: error: /f/Coursework/Code/python/compile/built/../ATLAS//CONFIG/src/probe_arch.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [probe_arch.o] Error 1
gcc.exe: error: /f/Coursework/Code/python/compile/built/../ATLAS//CONFIG/src/probe_arch.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [probe_arch.o] Error 1
gcc -I/f/Coursework/Code/python/compile/built/../ATLAS//CONFIG/include  -g -w -o xisgcc /f/Coursework/Code/python/compile/built/../ATLAS//CONFIG/src/IsGcc.c atlconf_misc.o
gcc.exe: error: /f/Coursework/Code/python/compile/built/../ATLAS//CONFIG/src/IsGcc.c: No such file or directory
Makefile:39: recipe for target `xisgcc' failed
make: *** [xisgcc] Error 1

OS configured as Win64 (9)

Bad ASM value=0, res='NULL'

Assembly configured as  (0)

Bad VECFLAG value=0, res='NULL'

Vector ISA Extension configured as   (0,0)

Bad MACHTYPE value=0, res='NULL'

Architecture configured as  UNKNOWN (0)

Bad CPU MHZ value=0, res='NULL'

Clock rate configured as 0Mhz

Bad NCPU value=0, res='NULL'

Maximum number of threads configured as  0
Cannot detect CPU throttling.
ERROR 2 IN SYSCMND: 'make IRun_comp args="-v 0 -o atlconf.txt -O 9 -A 0 -Si nof77 0 -V 0   -b 64"'
xconfig exited with 2
```

Trying the same in the msys shell gives me:

```
make: `xconfig' is up to date.
./xconfig -d s /f/Coursework/Code/python/compile/built/../ATLAS/ -d b /f/Coursew
ork/Code/python/compile/built  -D c -DWALL -Si lapackref 1 -b 64 -Si archdef 0 -
Ss ADdir ../ATLAS/WINAD

Bad OS value=0, res='NULL'

OS configured as UNKNOWN (0)
Assertion failed: iret, file f:/Coursework/Code/python/compile/built/../ATLAS//C
ONFIG/src/config.c, line 602

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
xconfig exited with 3
```

The output of msysinfo is:

```
msysinfo-1.3: Send this to the MSYS support list:

MSYS 1.0.17(0.48/3/2) 2011-04-24 23:39 i686 unknown; targ=MINGW3
GNU bash, version 3.1.17(1)-release (i686-pc-msys); ENV=.profile
GNU Make 3.81This program built for i686-pc-msys; MAKE_MODE=unix
gcc.exe (GCC) 4.7.0; targ=MINGW32
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.22
224 2011-04-25 00:42:29.000000000 +0100 /bin/msys-1.0.dll
659 2010-04-14 15:15:29.000000000 +0100 /bin/msys-archive-2.dll
048 2011-09-10 07:40:32.000000000 +0100 /bin/msys-bz2-1.dll
240 2010-01-29 01:32:57.000000000 +0000 /bin/msys-crypt-0.dll
448 2010-04-14 23:32:54.000000000 +0100 /bin/msys-crypto-1.0.0.d
840 2010-01-29 02:06:29.000000000 +0000 /bin/msys-expat-1.dll
992 2010-01-29 01:49:36.000000000 +0000 /bin/msys-gdbm-3.dll
264 2010-01-29 01:49:36.000000000 +0000 /bin/msys-gdbm_compat-3.
548 2010-05-04 03:04:46.000000000 +0100 /bin/msys-gmp-10.dll
424 2010-05-08 20:26:27.000000000 +0100 /bin/msys-guile-17.dll
112 2010-05-08 20:26:27.000000000 +0100 /bin/msys-guile-srfi-srf
680 2010-05-08 20:26:27.000000000 +0100 /bin/msys-guile-srfi-srf
l
680 2010-05-08 20:26:27.000000000 +0100 /bin/msys-guile-srfi-srf
752 2010-05-08 20:26:27.000000000 +0100 /bin/msys-guile-srfi-srf
680 2010-05-08 20:26:27.000000000 +0100 /bin/msys-guilereadline-
904 2011-10-29 19:18:01.000000000 +0100 /bin/msys-iconv-2.dll
128 2011-10-29 12:22:30.000000000 +0100 /bin/msys-intl-8.dll
246 2010-09-26 06:04:09.000000000 +0100 /bin/msys-ltdl-7.dll
288 2011-09-10 08:01:59.000000000 +0100 /bin/msys-lzma-5.dll
248 2010-04-16 05:50:34.000000000 +0100 /bin/msys-magic-1.dll
064 2010-02-01 22:22:06.000000000 +0000 /bin/msys-minires.dll
544 2010-05-09 01:41:04.000000000 +0100 /bin/msys-opts-25.dll
608 2011-04-27 05:23:31.000000000 +0100 /bin/msys-perl5_8.dll
327 2010-04-28 00:40:27.000000000 +0100 /bin/msys-popt-0.dll
192 2010-02-01 22:29:13.000000000 +0000 /bin/msys-regex-1.dll
544 2010-04-14 23:32:54.000000000 +0100 /bin/msys-ssl-1.0.0.dll
864 2010-02-01 01:44:06.000000000 +0000 /bin/msys-termcap-0.dll
888 2010-02-01 21:40:02.000000000 +0000 /bin/msys-xml2-2.dll
920 2012-05-14 05:29:50.000000000 +0100 /bin/msys-z.dll
88 2010-04-29 19:18:53.000000000 +0100 /bin/make.exe
798 2012-03-31 18:24:11.000000000 +0100 /mingw/bin/gcc.exe
502 2011-11-30 15:20:43.000000000 +0000 /mingw/bin/ld.exe
HOME=/c/Users/Folcon
Sysname=MINGW32_NT-6.1  OSTYPE=msys  TERM=cygwin
PATH=.:/usr/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/MiK
TeX 2.9/miktex/bin:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/Sys
tem32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/c/Progra
m Files (x86)/ATI Technologies/ATI.ACE/Core-Static:/c/Program Fi
les (x86)/Git/cmd:/c/Program Files (x86)/Aspell/bin:/c/Program F
iles (x86)/gs/gs9.00/bin:/c/msys/gnuwin32/bin:/mingw/bin:/c/Prog
ram Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Emac
s/emacs/bin:/c/Python25/:/c/Program Files (x86)/TortoiseHg/:/c/P
rogram Files (x86)/Calibre2/:/c/lein:/c/mvn/bin:/c/Program Files
/TortoiseGit/bin:/c/Users/Folcon/.lein/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/
c/Program Files (x86)/Haskell/bin:/c/ghc/ghc-6.12.3/bin:/c/Progr
am Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine/:/c/Python26:/c/Python26/
DLLs:/c/Python26/Scripts:/c/Python26/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4:/c/
Python26/gnuplot/bin:/c/Python26/Lib/site-packages/vtk:/f/Progra
m Files (x86)/pythonxy/console:/f/Program Files (x86)/pythonxy/S
ciTE-2.21:/f/Program Files (x86)/pythonxy/mingw/bin:/c/Users/Fol
con/.lein/bin:/f/C/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin:/cygdrive/c/Progr
am Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin:/cygdrive/c/lein:/c/mvn/bin:
/cygdrive/c/Users/Folcon/.lein/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x8
6)/Haskell/bin:/cygdrive/c/ghc/ghc-6.12.3/bin:/cygdrive/c/Python
26:/cygdrive/c/Python26/DLLs:/cygdrive/c/Python26/Scripts:/cygdr
ive/c/Python26/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4:/cygdrive/c/Python26/gnup
lot/bin:/cygdrive/c/Python26/Lib/site-packages/vtk:/cygdrive/c/U
sers/Folcon/.lein/bin:/cygdrive/f/C/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin
$ ls -tx /f/Coursework/Code/python/compile/built
config1.out   atlcomp.txt     Makefile    xprobe_OS.exe*
xconfig.exe*  atlconf_misc.o  probe_OS.o
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem?  I have been trying to build a 64 bit ATLAS lib on windows7 using the mingw64 toolchain but can't get past this first xconfig step. It seems like the -D c flag is causing the problem for me.

Comment: @mcheema I had some success, but not with the Windows 7 version, so I didn't end up updating it here as it was pretty specific to AWS which is where I ended up building it on. Had to just offload all the work I wanted to get done on it instead. Good luck and sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

- "Bad OS value" is caused by ATLAS using `tmpnam` function to generate temp file names (and trying to read command results from temp afterwards), which, in some MinGW implementations, returns paths to files in root directory (you can see "Access denied" and "cat: \XXXX: No such file or directory" if you add `-v 2` to `.../configure` args).

You can try to mitigate the issue by changing ATL_tmpnam function to use `tempnam`  to return temp files inside current directory (which you should have write access to), instead:

(the following is, of course, a dirty hack and could be made better)

```
--- -   2016-08-17 18:06:53.413941900 +0300
+++ ATLAS/CONFIG/include/atlas_sys.h    2016-08-17 16:54:37.583946600 +0300
@@ -218,10 +218,14 @@ static char *ATL_tmpnam(void)
 {
    static char tnam[L_tmpnam];
    static char FirstTime=1;
+   char* temptnam;
    if (FirstTime)
    {
       FirstTime = 0;
-      assert(tmpnam(tnam));
+      temptnam = tempnam(".",tnam);
+      assert(temptnam);
+      strcpy(tnam,temptnam);
+      free(temptnam);
    }
    return(tnam);
 }
```

- `gcc: /f/Coursework/Code/python/compile/built/../ATLAS//CONFIG/src/probe_asm.c: No such file or directory
  gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files` with perfectly valid (for Cygwin) file paths is caused by running wrong gcc: if you run `which gcc`, you'll see that it's not from Cygwin's `/usr/bin/` but from some other place in your system (possibly added to `%PATH%` by MinGW). Being not "aware" of Cygwin, it considers these paths non-existent. Solution: add `--cc=/usr/bin/gcc` or a similar argument to `.../configure`.